# CoreData - Fetch request with relationship object

Tags: ios, nspredicate, relationships

please confirm if i understand that right...

Imagine there is an entity 'person' and an entity 'credit_card'.
So **one** 'person' can have **many** 'credit_card's.

The person entity has the attributes: **name: STRING** and **age: INT**
and relationship: **creditcards** (to many) inverse

and the credit card entity has: **card_number: INT** and **valid_date: DATE** and relationship: **card_user** (to one) inverse

In my code i have a specific person (ManagedObject) called f.e. Person ***currentUser**. If i now want to get all credit cards of this specific person **with a specific 'valid_date'** i would create a fetch request (for Entity 'credit_card') with following predicates:

```
NSPredicate *predicate1 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
@"valid_date == <NSDate object>"];

NSPredicate *predicate2 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
@"ANY card_user like currentUser"];
```

This predicate works well for me, but is that the right way? Should i really ask for: "ANY **relationship name** like **ManagedObject**" ?

Comment: [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
@"card_user  == %@ AND valid_date == %@", currentUser, date];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding what you want correctly, all you need to do is use the `creditcards` property on your `Person *currentUser` and filter it down:

```
NSSet *setOfCreditCards = currentUser.creditcards;
NSPredicate *filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"valid_date == %@", date];
NSSet *cardsWithValidDates = [setOfCreditCards filteredSetUsingPredicate:filter];
```

The reason you tell `CoreData` about relationships is to avoid making another query from scratch.

Comment: Ah ok ^^. My fault. There is no fetch request neccessary. I should get the credit cards WITH THE CORRECT 'valid_date' from the creditcards set. Isn't it?

Comment: You don't need a second fetch request, but you can leverage your knowledge of NSPredicate to filter the set quickly

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use the ANY key word if you have set up you core data model correctly. Specifically Credit cards need to have a person relationship back to the person object (you should get a warning if you didn't do this). Then you could combine both predicates into one like this

```
NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"person == %@ AND valid_date == %@", currentUser, valid_date];
```